# Distance Metric between 2 lists of sets

Tags: distance, jaccard-coefficient

I have 2 list of of sets and I want to calculate a distance.

```
set1 = [
  {'A', 'B', 'C'},
  {'A', 'D', 'X'},
  {'X', 'A'}
]

set2 = [
  {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
  {'A', 'X'},
  {'X', 'A', 'B'}
]
```

So if the set of sets are equal I want the distance to be 0, and if unequal then I want the distance to be higher than 0.

The exact distance doesn't really matter as I'll ultimately be aggregating to compare multiple approaches to predicting this list of sets, so I really just need a relative distance.

My initial thought was a sum of Jaccard Distances, but I'm not sure how that would turn out.

Comment: Maybe ```1 - sum([x == y for x,y in zip(set1,set2)])/max(len(set1),len(set2))```

Comment: Will you always have the same amount of sets in both lists?

Comment: @Tasos Yeah, the length of the lists will be the same. They are pairwise sets.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

For pairwise comparison calculate each  Jaccard distance and take the norm.

```
from numpy.linalg import norm

norm([ 1 - len(set.intersection(*p)) / len(set.union(*p)) for p in zip(set1,set2) ])
```

> ```
> 0.5335936864527374
> ```

**OP**

You can calculate the Jaccard distance.

With `set1` and `set2` in OP then

```
sc = list(map(lambda st: { ''.join(s) for s in st }, [set1, set2]))
1 - len(set.intersection(*sc)) / len(set.union(*sc))
```

> ```
> 0.8
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this is basically Jaccard distance between set1 and set2, but I would really like a pairwise aggregation to draw out more subtlety.

Comment: @pettinato See update for pairwise aggregation.

Comment: A norm of some sort is a good idea, thanks!